# How to test serilog's diagnosticContext is set with the correct values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, serilog

I am writing a unit test for testing serilog's `diagnosticContext` is set with the correct properties and values.  But I cannot get any properties from `diagnosticContext`. Is there a way to assert that the properties are set correctly? [image: test diagnosticContext]

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/189

Comment: @HenriqueMauri, thanks!  I ended up using mocks.

Comment: Could you answer your question by posting the sample code you made? That way you can help other people with the same doubts.

Comment: @HenriqueMauri, I missed your comment. Here it is https://devops.wisetechglobal.com/wtg/BorderWise/_git/UMP/pullrequest/47830?_a=files